# Get pressed key in pynput GlobalHotkeys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I need to get the pressed key of `GlobalHotkeys` so that I can filter key combinations. Using `Listener` objects you can do this by passing `on_press` and `on_release` parameters. But if I do it in `GlobalHotkeys` it's giving me an error. How do I do this?

Here's my code:

```
# MyHotkeys.py
class MyHotkeys(GlobalHotKeys):
    def __init__(self, hotkeys):
        super().__init__(hotkeys, darwin_intercept=self.my_filter)
    def my_filter(self, t, e):
        pass

# main.py
def my_func():
    # How to get pressed key here?
    print("hello world")

my_hotkeys = MyHotkeys ({"<ctrl>+i": my_func})
```

This is how you can get the pressed key using `Listener`

```
def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('pressed', key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key pressed', key)

def on_release(key):
    print('released', key)
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

listener = Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Please explain what you are trying to do in a different way ??

Comment: @ScottC I've edited the question to show how to get the pressed key using `Listener`

Comment: Not really an answer, but while debugging, I altered the pynput->keyboard->__init__.py file.  Specifically, added prints to the `HotKey.press` and `HotKey.press` functions to display when keys were pressed and released.  In the press function, you can alter `self._on_activate()` to pass in the `key` (last pressed to trigger) or the `self._state` (all keys to trigger), which will then pass it to your function.